# Write n bytes from a file into another in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, file-management, bash-scripting, binary-files

Hello how can I write `n` bytes from one file into a new file starting from the `k` position using Bash?

- For example if n=60, k=1 and file size=100 then: the 2nd file would consist of from the 1st byte up to the 60th byte and would be 60 bytes in size
- For example if n=40, k=61 and file size=100 then: the 2nd file would consist of from the 61st byte up to the 100th byte and would be 40 bytes in size

Possibly we are working with binary files not ASCII files, so the concatenation of 2 halves should be identical to the original file!

(Is it possible with `dd` ?)

Comment: See `dd` and its `skip`, `count`, and `ibs` options.

Answer (score 19):

Yes.  Per the [dd man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd), you are looking for something like:

```
dd bs=1 count=60 if=_filename_1_ of=_filename_2_
dd bs=1 skip=60 count=40 if=_filename_1_ of=_filename_2_
```

where `_filename_n_` is replaced with an actual filename.

`bs=1` means that `count` and `skip` are byte counts.  `skip` is how many to skip; `count` is how many to copy.  **Edit** byte counts start from 0, not 1.  Therefore, to start at the first byte, use `skip=0` (or leave `skip` unspecified).

As a bash function, you could use:

```
# copy_nk(n, k, infile, outfile)
copy_nk() {
    dd bs=1 count="$1" skip="$2" ${3:+if="$3"} ${4:+of="$4"}
}
```

and then call it as

```
copy_nk 60 0 infile.txt outfile.txt
```

(with k=`0` because byte numbers start at zero).

With the `${3:+...}`, you can leave off the output file or the input file.  E.g.,

```
cat infile.txt | copy_nk 60 0 > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Does the index counter start from 0 or 1. So I guess if skip is `1` that means that it starts from the 2nd byte. Is that correct?

Comment: Using `bs=1` is _insanely_ slow, because `dd` will make two system calls per each byte. You can increase the copying speed by several orders of magnitude if you specify `bs` to be the largest size your RAM can handle that also divides both `skip` and `count` without remainder, then divide `skip` and `count` by that number.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another approach using `head` and bash command groups:

```bash
{ head -c60 > /dev/null ; head -c40 > output.txt ; } < input.txt
```

The first `head` here reads the first 60 bytes from input.txt and sends it to the bit bucket.

Because these `head` commands are within the command group, the file position within input.txt will be preserved.  Thus the second `head` will read the next 40 bytes (from byte 61 to 100 using 1-based indexing), and write it to output.txt.

---

In fact this method can be generalized to give `split`-like functionality, but with the added benefit of being able to specify the length of each output file.  Suppose we have a 100 byte file that we want to split into chunks of sizes 7, 50, 23, and the remainder.  We could do:

```bash
{
    head -c7 > 7bytes.txt
    head -c50 > 50bytes.txt
    head -c23 > 23bytes.txt
    cat > remaining-bytes.txt
} < input.txt
```

Comment: You can corrupt a filesystem with `head` just as easily (or easier), if you're crazy enough to pipe its output to a block device. Of course, you wouldn't do that -- you'd use `dd` instead, or something else meant for the job. The reason for `dd`'s scary reputation is that it's just robust enough that you *can* more or less safely use it for intrinsically dangerous tasks like cloning disk images, if you're careful enough. Of course, some people aren't and will mess up their disk -- but the reason for that isn't that they used `dd`, it's that they were messing with `/dev/sda` in the first place.

Comment: Very nice!  I didn't know about `head -c`.

Comment: You can only corrupt a filesystem if you're running as root. And if you're root you can corrupt it with practically any utility that writes to files.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Fair enough - I've removed the unnecessary anti-`dd` FUD.